# ggsankey: Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs

Tags: r, error-handling

I'm new using ggsankey.

I have the following data

```
t1 <- sample(x = c("Hosp A", "Hosp B", "Hosp C","Hosp D") , size = 100, replace=TRUE)
t2 <- sample(x = c("Male", "Female")   , size = 100, replace=TRUE)'''
d <- data.frame(cbind(t1,t2))
names(d) <- c('Hospital', 'Gender')
head(d)
 Hospital Gender
1   Hosp D   Male
2   Hosp D Female
3   Hosp D Female
4   Hosp A Female
5   Hosp A Female
6   Hosp B   Male
```

Then I used the make_long function

```
df <- d %>%
make_long(Hospital, Gender)

pl <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x
                 , next_x = next_x
                 , node = node
                 , next_node = next_node
                 , fill = factor(node)
                 , label = node))
pl +geom_sankey(flow.alpha = 0.5
            , node.color = "black"
            ,show.legend = FALSE)
```

This last part shows me the error:

> "Error: `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs."

Could someone please help me!

Comment: I forgot saying that I'm using R version 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you have already loaded the plyr (or Hmisc) package. I think that once you detach these packages, your problem should be solved.
See this [link](https://datacornering.com/dplyr-error-n-must-only-be-used-inside-dplyr-verbs/)! for more specifics on this issue.
Hope this helps.